# Composer: How to define repositories for internal Gitlab projects with hierarchy?

Tags: composer-php, repository, gitlab

I have three projects (p1, p2, p3) in a local Gitlab installation. The project p1 requires p2, the project p2 requires p3.

The p2/composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "my-group/p2",
    ...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@git.local.dev/my-group/p3.git"
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "gitlab-token": {
            "gitlab.com": "my-token"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "my-group/p3": "dev-develop"
    }
}
```

The command 'composer install' works for the p2 project without any problems.

The p1/composer.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "my-group/p1",
    ...
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@git.local.dev/my-group/p2.git"
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "gitlab-token": {
            "gitlab.com": "my-token"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "my-group/p2": "dev-develop"
    }
}
```

The command 'composer install' displays for the project p1 the following error message:

```
$ composer install
...
Problem 1
  - Installation request for my-group/p2 dev-develop -> satisfiable by my-group/p2[dev-develop].
  - my-group/p2 dev-develop requires my-group/p3 dev-develop -> no matching package found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repository, the `repositories` option is only evaluated from the root `composer.json`. So, if you don't make p3 available through satis or some other services that covers multiple repositories, this won't work

Comment: Thanks @nico-haase. I marked your answer as correct, because it is in general the correct solution. But in my case, it is not. On our current server is a ruby-script that loops through all branches and tags of all projects in our local Gitlab installation and if it contains a `composer.json`, adds it to our internal repository. But the application is not stable, so I want to use something different. I can test satis, but I'm afraid, that it will not be better.

Comment: So, if you have a general repository system, why not link it? If you use `ssh://git@git.local.dev/my-group/p3.git`, you reference a single project and not a composer repository. If you can provide a `packages.json` anywhere with a reference to all projects, you might be done

Comment: I do not link it, because I try to find a way, how to install requirements without the general repository system. The repository system is quite unstable and causes oft deployment problems.

Answer (score 1):

The following composer.json works:

```
{
    "name": "my-group/p1",
    ...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@git.local.dev/my-group/p2.git"
        },
                {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@git.local.dev/my-group/p3.git"
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "gitlab-token": {
            "gitlab.com": "my-token"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "my-group/p2": "dev-develop"
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I do not know, what the project p2 requires and I do not want to have all internal projects in the composer.json.